# How do you detect the main hard drive letter such as C: drive?

Tags: c#

How do you detect the main hard drive letter such as C: drive?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try

```
Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
```

That will return (normally) C:\

But it depends on how you define the "main" hard drive. This will give you the drive Windows is installed on.

Comment: To be compatible with Linux it looks like only `UserProfile` is guaranteed so use `Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile))`

Answer (score 22):

This should work (assuming you want the drive that windows is on):

```
string rootDrive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (at least for Windows).
What does this do on macOS, Linux, Android & iOS I wonder?

Answer (score 4):

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System).Substring(0,1)
```

Reference from [here](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/579727-c-get-windows-drive/).

Answer (score 3):

"SystemDrive" is the environment variable on XP that you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"));
```